# Gitian windows compile not working (time error)

Tags: windows, time, compiler-errors, debian

So I am making my own cryptocurrency and i want to compile it on windows so I installed gitian and the whole process and I get stuck on an error,

```
Creating build script (var/build-script)
fatal: unknown date format format-local:%F %T
./bin/gbuild:149:in `block (2 levels) in build_one_configuration': error looking up author-date in jatcoin (RuntimeError)
        from ./bin/gbuild:145:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:145:in `block in build_one_configuration'
        from ./bin/gbuild:129:in `open'
        from ./bin/gbuild:129:in `build_one_configuration'
        from ./bin/gbuild:320:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from ./bin/gbuild:315:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:315:in `block in <main>'
        from ./bin/gbuild:313:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:313:in `<main>'
```

Possible soulotions:
Updating git (I dont know how on debian)
wrong line in my gitain-win32.yml.

Please help jojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change line 148 in gitian-builder/bin/gbuild

author_date = `cd inputs/#{dir} && TZ=UTC git log --date=format-local:%F %T --format="%ad" -1`.strip

by this

author_date = `cd inputs/#{dir} && TZ=UTC git log --date=local --format="%ad" -1`.strip

Answer (score -1):

I got an error until i discovered you need a ` symbol before cd inputs and before the .strip